# Auto selecionar option de uma select a partir de um input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um formulário, onde ele coleta dados dos Correios através do CEP.
Eu tenho o seguinte imput:

```
<input type="text" name="estado" id="estado" />
```

Se a pessoa preencheu um cep de São Paulo, este input acima recebe o valor: SP

Gostaria que o campo select abaixo fosse selecionado automaticamente com a opção de "São Paulo". No caso o select:

`<option value="464">São Paulo</option>`

#### Codigo

```
<select name="zone_id" id="input-order-zone" class="form-control" data-value="" data-cep="uf">
<option value=""> --- Selecione --- </option>
<option value="440">Acre</option>
<option value="441">Alagoas</option>
<option value="442">Amapá</option>
<option value="443">Amazonas</option>
<option value="444">Bahia</option>
<option value="445">Ceará</option>
<option value="446">Distrito Federal</option>
<option value="447">Espírito Santo</option>
<option value="448">Goiás</option>
<option value="449">Maranhão</option>
<option value="450">Mato Grosso</option>
<option value="451">Mato Grosso do Sul</option>
<option value="452">Minas Gerais</option>
<option value="453">Pará</option>
<option value="454">Paraíba</option>
<option value="455">Paraná</option>
<option value="456">Pernambuco</option>
<option value="457">Piauí</option>
<option value="458">Rio de Janeiro</option>
<option value="459">Rio Grande do Norte</option>
<option value="460">Rio Grande do Sul</option>
<option value="461">Rondônia</option>
<option value="462">Roraima</option>
<option value="463">Santa Catarina</option>
<option value="464">São Paulo</option>
<option value="465">Sergipe</option>
<option value="466">Tocantins</option>
</select>
```

Comment: As `options` deste select tem value?

Comment: Tem sim, não ta aparecendo pra você?

Comment: Wendell, eu editei e consegui ve, para adicionar HTML puro use **{}**

Comment: Wendell, pode adicionar o html do input que a pessoa digita o cep tambem?

Answer (score 2):

Para realizar essa ação você deve ter algum tipo de vinculo do valor com os `option` do `select`

```js
function onEstadoChange(value){
  var regex = new RegExp(value, 'i'); // CRIA UM REGEX QUE VAI IGNORAR MAISCULA/MINUSCULA
  var option = jQuery('#input-order-zone').find('option').filter(function(){
    jQuery(this).removeAttr('selected'); // COMO ESTA ITERANDO TODOS OS option JA APROVEITO PARA REMORES O ATRIBUTO SELECTED
    return jQuery(this).attr('data-sigla').match(regex) != null;
  });
  var opValue = option.attr('value');
  jQuery('#input-order-zone').val(opValue);
}


jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('#estado').on('change', function(){ // CRIA UM EVENTO change QUE É DISPARADO QUANDO O CONTEUDO MUDA
    var value = this.value; // PEGA O VALOR
    onEstadoChange(value);
  });
  onEstadoChange('MG');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="estado" id="estado" />

<select name="zone_id" id="input-order-zone" class="form-control" data-value="" data-cep="uf">
  <option value="" data-sigla=""> --- Selecione --- </option>
  <option value="440" data-sigla="">Acre</option>
  <option value="441" data-sigla="">Alagoas</option>
  <option value="442" data-sigla="">Amapá</option>
  <option value="443" data-sigla="">Amazonas</option>
  <option value="444" data-sigla="">Bahia</option>
  <option value="445" data-sigla="">Ceará</option>
  <option value="446" data-sigla="">Distrito Federal</option>
  <option value="447" data-sigla="">Espírito Santo</option>
  <option value="448" data-sigla="">Goiás</option>
  <option value="449" data-sigla="">Maranhão</option>
  <option value="450" data-sigla="">Mato Grosso</option>
  <option value="451" data-sigla="">Mato Grosso do Sul</option>
  <option value="452" data-sigla="MG">Minas Gerais</option>
  <option value="453" data-sigla="">Pará</option>
  <option value="454" data-sigla="">Paraíba</option>
  <option value="455" data-sigla="">Paraná</option>
  <option value="456" data-sigla="">Pernambuco</option>
  <option value="457" data-sigla="">Piauí</option>
  <option value="458" data-sigla="">Rio de Janeiro</option>
  <option value="459" data-sigla="">Rio Grande do Norte</option>
  <option value="460" data-sigla="">Rio Grande do Sul</option>
  <option value="461" data-sigla="">Rondônia</option>
  <option value="462" data-sigla="">Roraima</option>
  <option value="463" data-sigla="">Santa Catarina</option>
  <option value="464" data-sigla="SP">São Paulo</option>
  <option value="465" data-sigla="">Sergipe</option>
  <option value="466" data-sigla="">Tocantins</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Eu não coloquei todas as sigla, mas é so ir preenchendo. Caso não queira poluir com `data-sigla`, avise que tenho outra resposta, esse seria a mais simples.

Comment: Guilherme, eu vi que seu código aqui funcionou. Mas ao inserir em minha página, não está funcionando. Ao "Inspecionar" no Google Chrome, vi que não aparece a opção "data-sigla" nas opções, porém se eu clicar para exibir o código fonte aparece. E se eu editar o código através da opção "Inspecionar" do Chrome e inserir o "data-sigla" a função funciona. O que será que está acontecendo?

Comment: @Wendell Provavelmente você esta gerando os `option` no seu PHP, através de um array, seria necessário inserir junto na `option` quando ela é criada.

Comment: Eu estou utilizando a plataforma Opencart. O código original do select era assim: `<select name="zone_id" id="input-order-zone" class="form-control" data-value="<?php echo $zone_id; ?>">`  Porém como as opções "value" no     select     são fixas eu substitui o código original pelo seu.

Comment: @Wendell não consigo lhe auxiliar, eu teria de saber mais sobre o contexto.

Comment: Guilherme, consegui resolver esta questão mudando o id. Porém tem um outro problema, acredito que consegue me ajudar. O campo `<input type="text" name="estado" id="estado" />` é preenchido automaticamente quando eu insiro o CEP e desta forma o select não é alterado, seu código funciona somente quando eu digito o valor no campo `<input type="text" name="estado" id="estado" />`.

Comment: @Wendell adicionei colocando uma alternativa. Assim é so chamar a função com o valor

Comment: @Wendell eu tive de fazer uma alteração no código, verifique :D

Comment: a função continua funcionando somente se eu clicar no campo e alterar o valor manualmente. Sem fazer isso o select fica a todo tempo marcado como "Minas Gerais". Quando digito o cep em outro campo e o campo `<input type="text" name="estado" id="estado" />` altera automaticamente o select continua como "Minas Gerais".

Comment: @Wendell quando você faz a alteração do cep, este deve retornar o estado ("SP", "MG"), então chamar a função com este valor.

Comment: Justamente. Ele me retorna a sigla do estado referente ao CEP que eu digitei. E nos campos `data-sigla` já estão todos preenchidos com a sua respectiva sigla. Eu utilizo esta função para captar o estado: https://viacep.com.br/exemplo/javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Inclua o Javascript/Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#estado").on("change", function(){
        var estado = $(this).val();
        $("#input-order-zone option[sigla='" + estado + "']").prop("selected", true);
    });
});
```

Substitua seu `select` por este:

```
<select name="zone_id" id="input-order-zone" class="form-control" data-value="" data-cep="uf">
    <option value="" sigla=""> --- Selecione --- </option>
    <option value="440" sigla="AC">Acre</option>
    <option value="441" sigla="AL">Alagoas</option>
    <option value="442" sigla="AP">Amapá</option>
    <option value="443" sigla="AM">Amazonas</option>
    <option value="444" sigla="BA">Bahia</option>
    <option value="445" sigla="CE">Ceará</option>
    <option value="446" sigla="DF">Distrito Federal</option>
    <option value="447" sigla="ES">Espírito Santo</option>
    <option value="448" sigla="GO">Goiás</option>
    <option value="449" sigla="MA">Maranhão</option>
    <option value="450" sigla="MT">Mato Grosso</option>
    <option value="451" sigla="MS">Mato Grosso do Sul</option>
    <option value="452" sigla="MG">Minas Gerais</option>
    <option value="453" sigla="PA">Pará</option>
    <option value="454" sigla="PB">Paraíba</option>
    <option value="455" sigla="PR">Paraná</option>
    <option value="456" sigla="PE">Pernambuco</option>
    <option value="457" sigla="PI">Piauí</option>
    <option value="458" sigla="RJ">Rio de Janeiro</option>
    <option value="459" sigla="RN">Rio Grande do Norte</option>
    <option value="460" sigla="RS">Rio Grande do Sul</option>
    <option value="461" sigla="RO">Rondônia</option>
    <option value="462" sigla="RR">Roraima</option>
    <option value="463" sigla="SC">Santa Catarina</option>
    <option value="464" sigla="SP">São Paulo</option>
    <option value="465" sigla="SE">Sergipe</option>
    <option value="466" sigla="TO">Tocantins</option>
</select>
```

Comment: João Paulo, eu vi que seu código aqui funcionou. Mas ao inserir em minha página, não está funcionando. Ao "Inspecionar" no Google Chrome, vi que não aparece a opção "sigla" nas opções, porém se eu clicar para exibir o código fonte da página a opção "sigla" aparece. E se eu editar o código através da opção "Inspecionar" do Chrome e inserir o "sigla" nas opções a sua função funciona. O que será que está acontecendo?

Comment: Você atualizou o html e mesmo assim no navegador não apareceu o "sigla" ?